# Vue.js dynamic <style> + variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to pass a dynamic variable into style, is that possible?  I tried this way but it didn't work:

```
:style="{'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`% ;}"
```

This is my *task.vue*:

```
 <tr  v-for="task in tasks.data "  v-if=" task.projet_id == key "   :key="task.id">
       <td >{{ parseInt(100 * task.progress) }}% <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" :style=" 
        {'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`% ;}"  id="progress" 
       aria-valuemin="`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
       </div>             
       </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There [sure is a way](https://jsfiddle.net/shanemendez/afo1xmn0/8/) to do what you are looking for, I linked a demo for you.

#### Lets look deeper

We can take a look at your `v-bind` syntax

```
<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" :style=" 
        {'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`% ;}"  id="progress" 
       aria-valuemin="`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
       </div>
```

I'll simplify this a little bit

```
<div 
    :style="{'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`% ;}">
</div>
```

Here I can see that you've *bound* `style` to the `expression`

```
{'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`% ;}
```

we can see that you're creating an `Object` with key `width` and who's value is another `expression`

```
`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`%
```

here we see the use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), a feature of vanilla javascript.

> Template literals are enclosed by the backtick (` `)
>
> Template literals can contain placeholders
>
> [Placeholders] are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (${expression})

When javascript sees this this syntax, the `expression` is evaluated, and this is where we find the first syntax error

```
//In
`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`%

//The expression is "parseInt(100 * task.progress)"
//simplifying we get
`${expression}`%

//and we know that `${expression}` is a string
```

It might be easier to see now that

```
"string"%
```

Doesn't make syntacitical sense.
The solution? Put the `%` *inside* the `template literal`

```
`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}%`
```

Simple enough

#### moving back up

`` {'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`% ;} ``

can be changed to

`` {'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}%` ;} ``

but `;` don't belong in `object`. For example, `{'attr':'1';}` is invalid. That leaves us with

`` {'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}%`} ``

### fin

as a challenge to the reader, this is equivalent

```
:style="{'width':parseInt(100 * task.progress)}+'%'}"
```

The links provided should be enough to help understand.

TLDR: You have a syntax error; `` :style="{'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}%`}" `` works

Answer (score 3):

It looks alright except for some syntax errors:

```html
:style="{'width': `${parseInt(100 * progress)}%`}"
```

- The binding is to an object, so a `;` would be out of place
- The `%` needs to be inside the string

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to add variables inside `style`. In your case the `%` should be inside the quotes.

```
<tr  v-for="task in tasks.data "  v-if=" task.projet_id == key "   :key="task.id">
       <td >{{ parseInt(100 * task.progress) }}% <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" :style=" 
        {'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}%`}"  id="progress" 
       aria-valuemin="`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}`" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
       </div>             
</td>
```

It is not needs to include `;` while adding style since the style data is an object and will be separated by `commas` like this

```
:style="{'width':`${parseInt(100 * task.progress)}%`, color:'red'}"
```